# ssms to oracle openquery DATEADD

Tags: sql, oracle, openquery

New to using Openquery and trying to pull data from current month and last month. 
typically I would just use DATEADD for getting specific dates but OpenQuery doesn't seem to like it. Any tips on how to pull from current month and previous month?

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(TestServer,'

        SELECT name
            ,number
            ,create_date
            ,carton
            ,trailer
            ,bol
        FROM TEST.TESTING_VIEW1 TestV
        WHERE (TestV.create_date>=DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) OR TestV.create_date IS NULL)
    ')
```

Comment: That query is run on the Oracle server and Oracle has no `dateadd()` you can use `current_date - interval '1' month` instead, or `add_month(current_date, -1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY(TestServer,'
        SELECT name
            ,number
            ,create_date
            ,carton
            ,trailer
            ,bol
        FROM TEST.TESTING_VIEW1 TestV
        WHERE (TestV.create_date>= add_months(TRUNC(current_date,''MONTH''), -1) 
           OR TestV.create_date IS NULL)
    ');
```

SQL Server to Oracle:

```
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)
<=> 
add_months(TRUNC(current_date,'MONTH'), -1)
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7392acbc9c1420d24ee62d313d767a4e)**